# Should I use try-catch or built in error handling?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a project with my friend. He follows this method of writing codes. Is it good or bad? I'm also not that much experience developer.

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {  
    try   
    {  
        $comment = new TicketComment();  
        $comment->content = $request['comment'];  
        $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;  
        $comment->ticket_id = $request['ticketId'];  
        $comment->save();  
        $ticket = Ticket::where('id', '=', $comment->ticket_id)->first();  
        $ticket->updated_at = $comment->created_at;  
        $ticket->update();  
    }    
    catch(Exception $e)  
    {  
        request()->session()->flash('unsuccessMessage', 'Failed to add comment !!!');  
        return redirect()->back();  
    }  
    request()->session()->flash('successMessage', 'Comment has been successfully added !!!');  
    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

Comment: yes, it is good to have `try-catch` block here

Comment: @Ronak Dhoot can you please explain why?

Comment: No, you don't **need** a `try-catch` block.  As mentioned in the answer below, Laravel does have its own error handling system so any exception thrown would be caught and reported by Laravel. That being said, a `try-catch` block, in this care, is good for showing more specific errors to a user but it will come at the expense of not recording a stack trace of the underlying error. In the long run, and in its current state, it will be harder to debug your code as you'll know something has gone wrong but you won't know what.

Comment: This entire code is a very bad approach. It doesn't follow basic HTTP guidelines, returning  wrong HTTP codes, doesnt implement the Post./Redirect/Get pattern. While with correct approach it will need no try-catch at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't have a broad Exception catch block. Only catch exceptions you expect to be thrown in that block that way you can properly log unexpected exceptions and fix any other bugs in your code that may have caused those, instead of hiding them from yourself.

If you must do this then it might be in the context of something like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {  
    try   
    {  
        $comment = new TicketComment();  
        $comment->content = $request['comment'];  
        $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;  
        $comment->ticket_id = $request['ticketId'];  
        $comment->save();  
        $ticket = Ticket::where('id', '=', $comment->ticket_id)->first();  
        $ticket->updated_at = $comment->created_at;  
        $ticket->update();  
    }    
    catch(Exception $e)  
    {  
        if (!($e instanceof SQLException)) {
            app()->make(\App\Exceptions\Handler::class)->report($e); // Report the exception if you don't know what actually caused it
        }
        request()->session()->flash('unsuccessMessage', 'Failed to add comment !!!');  
        return redirect()->back();  

    }  
    request()->session()->flash('successMessage', 'Comment has been successfully added !!!');  
    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

This way any unexpected exceptions will still be reported and you can go through your logs later to fix any bugs that are causing them.

As a reminder since PHP 7.1 you can have a union of exceptions in a catch block ([Reference](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/multiple-catch)) e.g.

```
try { } 
catch (ExceptionType1|ExceptionType2 $e) {

}
```

This way you can handle the exceptions you know you can handle and let Laravel handle the ones you are not sure how to handle.

Note that you generally don't have to have `try-catch` blocks in controller code, you can always use the exception handler to do the flash/redirect back combination for all unhandled exceptions if that is your preferred way of handling them.

Answer (score 3):

It is allways good to handle the errors. However, Laravel has built in error handling, which ease this process. This does not mean you dont need the try catch block.
Read more about laravel error handling: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

Comment: Do we need to worry about the controller being lengthy?

Comment: To shorten your controller, create and use repository and service classes.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I handled the same. I logged the error instead of returning it to user interface.

```
public function postData()
{
 try
  {
    //your logics to post goes here
  } 
      catch (\Exception $exception) {

                if (!($exception instanceof \SQLiteException)) {
                    app()->make(\App\Exceptions\Handler::class)->report($exception); // Report the exception if you don't know what actually caused it

                }
                Alert::toast('Error Toast', 'An error occurred');

                \Log::error($exception);

                return redirect()->back();

            }
            Alert::success('SuccessAlert', 'alert');
            return back();
        }
```